# Why multilevel sort using sorted function in python get the wrong answer?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

This post is not the same as [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by values of the dictionary in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/in-python-how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-of-the-dictionary/73050#73050), which I think can not be solved using lambda sort, since the sort should be done on two properties, one ascending and the other descending.

I think it's answer should be

**descending on column 2 and ascending on column 3**

```
[1, 5, 7]
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 2, 9]
[3, 1, 9]
```

but the output is:

```
[1, 5, 7]
[2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3]
**[3, 2, 2]**   i think it's wrong here
[4, 2, 9]
[3, 1, 9]
```

The code is as follows

```
l=[
        [1,2,3],
        [2,3,4],
        [1,5,7],
        [3,1,9],
        [3,2,2],
        [4,2,9]
   ]

def printlist(l):
    for ll in l:
        print ll

def comp1(a,b):
    if a[1]<b[1]:
        return 1
    if a[1]==b[1]:
        return a[2]>b[2]
    else:
        return -1

l3=sorted(l,cmp=comp1)
printlist(l3)
```

So why the program output the wrong answer?

**Edit1**:
Here I choose `cmp` rather than `key=itemgetter(2,3)` since there could be more complex structures, which can not be sorted using `itemgetter`, but can only be sorted using the `cmp` function.

Comment: `cmp` has been removed in Python3, and the reason is everything can be done with `key` and it is much more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `comp1` function should return a positive or negative integer:

http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sorted

> cmp specifies a custom comparison function of two arguments (iterable
>   elements) which should return **a negative, zero or positive number**
>   depending on whether the first argument is considered smaller than,
>   equal to, or larger than the second argument: cmp=lambda x,y:
>   cmp(x.lower(), y.lower()). The default value is None.

In the following line you are returning a boolean value:

```
return a[2]>b[2]
```

According to the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values):

> Boolean values are the two constant objects False and True. They are
>   used to represent truth values (although other values can also be
>   considered false or true). In numeric contexts (for example when used
>   as the argument to an arithmetic operator), they behave like the
>   integers 0 and 1, respectively.

Therefore `False` returns `0` instead of `-1`. Replace it with

```
return a[2] - b[2]
```

and you are good to go.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
>>> sorted(l, key= lambda x:(-x[1], x[2]))
[
    [1, 5, 7], 
    [2, 3, 4], 
    [3, 2, 2], 
    [1, 2, 3], 
    [4, 2, 9], 
    [3, 1, 9]
]
```

Comment: nice work:) but why the cmp way failed to reach the right answer? any bugs in the code?

Comment: @crazyminer False == 0 in Python, so according to your code `[1,2,3]` and  `[3, 2, 2]` are equal, and because Python's sort is stable sort `[1, 2, 3]` is returned first.